# None of the microsoft updates would install on my pc plus internet explorer stopped functioning as well

Tags: updates, internet-explorer-7

My pc would not accept any microsoft updates.Each time I try to go to microsoft download page, it says page not available be it internet explorer, firefox or google chrome. At the same time , the Internet explorer stopped working as well.
Can I please have a solution.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your internet connection - can you access any sites?
2. Run Anti-Virus, you might have a piece of malware preventing you from going to WindowsUpdate. Check your hosts file to see if some duff addresses have been put in there.